# Adding Google Analytics tracking code to contact form

Tags: php, google-analytics, event-tracking

I'd like to add Google event tracking to my PHP contact form.  Doing so requires me to add a particular value to the 'onsubmit' attribute of the  element.  My PHP file already has an 'onsubmit' attribute defined.  When I delete that attribute and enter the required Google code, nothing happens when I click the 'Submit' button (i.e. form does not submit, 'Thank You' page does not load, etc).

Here is the existing PHP code:

```
<form

class="cpp_form"

name="<?php echo $this->prefix; ?>_pform<?php echo '_'.$this->print_counter; ?>"

id="<?php echo $this->prefix; ?>_pform<?php echo '_'.$this->print_counter; ?>"

action="<?php $this->get_site_url(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"

onsubmit="return <?php echo $this->prefix; ?>_pform_doValidate<?php echo '_'.$this->print_counter; ?>(this);">
```

Here is the Google code I need to enter for onsubmit:

```
_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘button’, ’clicked’, ’contact us’,, ’true’])
```

Any ideas on how to do this/what I'm doing wrong?

I've also tried entering the Google code as the value for the "onclick" attribute.  When I do that, the form can successfully be submitted, but it does not show up as an 'event' in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

1) The GA code you posted shows smart-quotes. I'm not sure whether that's just a c/p thing posting here or if that's what you used in your actual code, but smart-quotes is invalid javascript syntax.

2) There are several ways you can do this. One way is to add it to your `onsubmit` as you tried. You don't need to replace the current stuff in there. Just add it to it. Since your current thing in there is returning something, you will want to add it before:

```
onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'button', 'clicked', 'contact us',,'true']); return <?php echo $this->prefix; ?>_pform_doValidate<?php echo '_'.$this->print_counter; ?>(this);">
```

Alternatively, you can look for where that xxx_pform_doValidate_xxx() function is defined and put your GA code in there.

3) To be clear, you are tracking that the form submit button was clicked.  In my experience, tracking form submit button clicks has little value, since it does not indicate that the form was successfully submitted, nor does it tell you why submission failed if it failed.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Let me try adding the code to onsubmit and see if I can get it to work.

>>  tracking form submit button clicks has little value, 

What might you suggest I track instead?  Is there a way to track *successful* form submissions?

Comment: Hey to update you, I tried inserting the 'onsubmit' code you suggested in #2).  However, now my 'Submit' button does not work.  I can mouse over it and the cursor changes as if it's a link, but clicking it does not do anything.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: the easiest way to track successful form submissions is to put your event on the form's "thank you" page.  As to why your code still doesn't work, did you make sure to change the smartquotes to regular quotes? Beyond that, I can't really tell you what's wrong since I don't have anything to go on except the code you posted here

Answer (score 0):

You could add the google code to your validation function or use a separate function where you first put the google code and then return the value of your validation function. Or add it inline before the `return` statement...

But as you have a "Thank You" page, you could also track that instead although that will not give you the client- and server-side unvalidated submissions.

Comment: Thanks for this.  How might I go about tracking the "Thank You" page loads?  I searched high and low for information on this, but couldn't find out how to track a page load.  It's probably easier than I'm expecting.

Comment: @user51204 you could set up a goal that is triggered every time that unless gets requested.

Comment: OK I'll look into that.  Can I set up that goal to only trigger when the page is loaded *from someone submitting the form.* (rather than when someone directly loads the "thank you" page URL)

Comment: @user51204 Yes, you can specify steps, I think it is called "funnels"